# read FTP file - performance improvement Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have FTP file with 100,000 records, each record i need to transform to XML and send it to Queue. Followed below strategy:

FTP->Splitter(kept all lines in List)->Transformer->Queue

Please suggest if we can do this better. How can i read the Splitter list with multiple threads parallel, instead of sequentially?

(in IBM Integration Bus (IIB) we have concept called 'Instances', is there anything similar to that ?)

I used below code, but doesn't seems to be working well. Please suggest if anything else is better ?

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
      <property name="corePoolSize" value="1"/>
      <property name="maxPoolSize" value="15"/>
      <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>  
</bean>
```

is it possible to keep multiple 'Open Output Count' ? if Multiple threads are posting the messages in Queue, it should by default open Multiple Open Output Counts ?

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter   id="jmsOut"
                                    channel="outputJMS"
                                    connection-factory="jmsQueueConnectionFactoryCached"
                                    destination="destinationQueue"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the big height it is just enough to make the splitter's `output-channel` as an `ExecutorChannel` to process some messages in parallel manner.

But! It doesn't guarantee that your target service (Queue?) isn't bottleneck by single-thread performance.

From other side, please, pay attention to the `FileSplitter` since Spring Integration 4.2. It allows do not read the entire file to the memory but lean on the `InputStream` for that `File`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. As you said, if messages are processed in parallel manner, then there should be multiple 'Open Output counts' to Queue. isn't it ?

Comment: If with that `Open Output counts` you just mean send messages over JMS using the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`, than no. you don't need concurrent senders there. The `JmsTemplate` is Thread-safe. Not sure where you have a problem. Maybe that `Transformer` does something bad from the multi-threading perspective...